# How do I connect to my running VM via virsh?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

My VM has already been started via `virsh start chameleon.ootbdev`. When I do a `virsh console chameleon.ootbdev` I get the following output:

```
Connected to domain chameleon.ootbdev
Escape character is ^]
error: internal error cannot find character device (null)
```

Doing a google search on this led me to this ["solution"](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Error_%22internal_error_cannot_find_character_device%22_when_trying_to_connect_a_domain%27s_console). Unfortunately, editing the domain via `virsh edit chameleon.ootbdev` doesn't seem to stick. I suspect the issue is that I'm inserting the XML incorrectly: the instructions from the link ask me to insert the following XML into the domain XML file.

```
<serial type='pty'>
   <target port='0'/>
 </serial>
 <console type='pty'>
   <target type='serial' port='0'/>
 </console>
```

I've posted my domain XML file to [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/Q70DDFzX). This is AFTER I've tried to insert the above XML. I inserted this XML after the `</devices>` block.

My primary question is: **How do I connect to the running VM?** A secondary question would be: **How do I edit the domain file with the above XML and get the changes to stick?**

Answer (score 2):

Serial ports and consoles are devices, too. Insert them there *before* the closing </devices> tag.